how to differentiate between "2024-08-20T17:29:55.7055383+05:30" and "2024-08-20T17:29:55.7055383" time "format" using dayjs
how to differentiate between "2024-08-20T17:29:55.7055383+05:30" and "2024-08-20T17:29:55.7055383" time "format" using dayjs
I'm trying to convert the timestamp "2024-08-20T17:29:55.7055383+05:30" to "2024-08-20T17:29:55.7055383" by removing the time zone offset, using dayjs. Despite experimenting with various dayjs functions, I haven't been successful in achieving the desired result. Any advice or guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

dayjs("2024-08-20T17:29:55.7055383+05:30").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS')
